# PHP settings check error(already changed 0 to -1)

Tags: magento

PHP Settings Check

Your PHP Version is 5.6.12, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using and explain your problem more in depth?

Comment: restarted the server after the change?

Comment: Please include error messages as text and not as referenced images.

Comment: yes i restared the server..@LuckyChingi

Comment: "Your PHP Version is 5.6.12, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider.".....this is the error message@NathanielFord

Answer (score 3):

@ Dipranil

Go to

`{magento_root}/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php`

And find this line and add  `return []; //`

```
private function checkPopulateRawPostSetting(){
    // HHVM and PHP 7does not support 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to be set to -1
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0-beta') >= 0 || defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
        return [];
}

return []; //       <-- ADD THIS LINE
[...]
```

Run again the Readiness Check: T
he PHP Settings Check gets a green light.
This is little bit dirty workaround but I cant find  another usefull solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to xampp
2. Open Folder php
3. Then Open File php.ini
4. find this

`;always_populate_raw_post_data = 0`

replace this

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```